# Nested np.where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe:

```
S A
1 1
1 0
2 1
2 0
```

I wanted to create a new `'Result'` column that is calculated based on the values of both column A and column S.

I wrote the following nested `np.where` code

```
df['Result'] = np.where((df.S == 1 & df.A == 1), 1,
                        (df.S == 1 & df.A == 0), 0,
                        (df.S == 2 & df.A == 1), 0,
                        (df.S == 2 & df.A == 0), 1))))
```

but when I execute it, I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Too many closing parentheses.

Comment: Thank you! I removed the extra closing parentheses, but I got instead the following error: ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3614, in __getattr__ return object.__getattribute__(self, name). AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know `np.where` does not support multiple return statements (at least not more than two). So either you rewrite your `np.where` to result in one True and one False statement and to return 1/0 for True/False, or you need to use masks.

If you rewrite `np.where`, you are limited to two results and the second result will always be set when the condition is not True. So it will be also set for values like `(S == 5) & (A = np.nan)`.

```
df['Result'] = np.where(((df.S == 1) & (df.A == 1)) | ((df.S == 2) & (df.A == 0)), 1, 0)
```

When using masks, you can apply an arbitrary number of conditions and results. For your example, the solution looks like:

```
mask_0 = ((df.S == 1) & (df.A == 0)) | ((df.S == 2) & (df.A == 1))
mask_1 = ((df.S == 1) & (df.A == 1)) | ((df.S == 2) & (df.A == 0))
df.loc[mask_0, 'Result'] = 0
df.loc[mask_1, 'Result'] = 1
```

Results will be set to `np.nan` where no condition is met. This is imho failsafe and should thus be used. But if you want to have zeros in these locations, just initialize your `Results` column with zeros.
Of course this can be simplified for special cases like only having 1 and 0 as result and extended for any number of result by using dicts or other containers.

Comment: is it possible with this approach to set not simply `1` or `0`, but take the value from another column? When trying it, I get `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`.

Comment: sure, I guess that should be easy. But without any sample data it is quite hard to give an answer. Could you please post a new question and post the link to it as a comment? I'll answer your new question in more detail.

Answer (score 16):

You should use nested np.where. It is like sql case clause. But be careful when there is nan in the data.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'S':[1,1,2,2],'A':[1,0,1,0]})
df['Result'] = np.where((df.S == 1) & (df.A == 1), 1,   #when... then
                 np.where((df.S == 1) & (df.A == 0), 0,  #when... then
                  np.where((df.S == 2) & (df.A == 1), 0,  #when... then
                    1)))                                  #else
df
```

## output:

```
|   | S | A | Result |
|---|---|---|--------|
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1      |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0      |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 0      |
| 3 | 2 | 0 | 1      |
```

Comment: Does this actually work? It doesn't look like they ran this on actual data in python (because they posted a markdown table of the results).

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend using [numpy.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) if you have very nested operations.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "S": [1, 1, 2, 2],
    "A": [1, 0, 1, 0]
})

# you could of course combine the clause (1, 4) and (2, 3) with the '|' or operator
df['RESULT'] = np.select([
    (df.S == 1) & (df.A == 1),
    (df.S == 1) & (df.A == 0),
    (df.S == 2) & (df.A == 1),
    (df.S == 2) & (df.A == 0)
], [1, 0, 0, 1])
```