# pandas dataframe masks to write values into new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mask

Based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54217790/973158), I created several masks on a Pandas dataframe to create a new column which should be filled from different columns (based on the conditions).

The (simplified) code looks as follows:

```
mask0 = (df['condition'] == 1)
mask1 = (df['condition'] == 0)

df.loc[mask0, 'newColumn'] = df['otherColumn1']
df.loc[mask1, 'newColumn'] = df['otherColumn2']
```

However upon execution of the third line I get the following error:

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

If I simply do this, it works:

```
df.loc[mask0, 'newColumn'] = 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to filter in both sides:

```
mask0 = (df['condition'] == 1)
mask1 = (df['condition'] == 0)

df.loc[mask0, 'newColumn'] = df.loc[mask0, 'otherColumn1']
df.loc[mask1, 'newColumn'] = df.loc[mask1, 'otherColumn2']
```

But here is better use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for avoid repeating code:

```
df['newColumn'] = np.select([mask0, mask1], 
                            [df['otherColumn1'], df['otherColumn2']], 
                            default=np.nan)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to mask the "*data provider*" as well:

```
df.loc[mask0, 'newColumn'] = df[mask0, 'otherColumn1']
df.loc[mask1, 'newColumn'] = df[mask1, 'otherColumn2']
```

If the first condition is true if the latter is false and vice versa, we can use `np.where(..)`:

```
df['newColumn'] = np.where(mask0, df['otherColumn0'], df['otherColumn2'])
```

or you can use `np.select(..)` in case the two can be both false where we fallback on the old values in case both conditons are `False`:

```
df['newColumn'] = np.select(
    [mask0, mask1],
    [df['otherColumn1'], df['otherColumn2']],
    default=df['newColumn']
)
```

Here of course we make the assumption that `newColumn` already exists in the dataframe (for example through some previous processing).

Comment: @jezrael: but the two are not the same. Since the default here uses the original values.

Comment: Yes, I see. So I think it is problem, because `newColumn` means column not exist I think, so cannot be used this way

Comment: @jezrael: well that's a bit vague. Since it might be a new column in the middle of some processing. But I will add a note :)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with `np.where`:

```
df['newColumn'] = np.where(df['condition'].eq(1), df['otherColumn1'], df['condition'])
df['newColumn'] = np.where(df['condition'].eq(0), df['otherColumn2'], df['condition'])
```